# How to estimate the local error and the global error for Runge-Kutta method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, computational-mathematics

How to estimate the local error and the global error for Runge-Kutta method in practice? I have no idea.

I recieved a nice answer on the question at other [site](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/how-to-estimate-the-local-error-and-the-global-error-for-runge-kutta-method)

Comment: This is certainly on-topic but make note of the [Computational Science site](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) for future numerical analysis topics.

Comment: Is there a particular Runge-Kutta method you have in mind?  Often we estimate numerical errors by comparing a given approach with one known to have higher order accuracy.  Choosing a pair of methods that share as much intermediate computation as possible to form these estimates is something of an art.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know about this site. I will post my questions there if you don't object.

Comment: I use Richardson extrapolation (adaptive step) for solving a system of differential equations.

Comment: I seen the following formula for estimate a global error: $\delta_{i+1} = \delta_{i}\cdot e^{\int^{t_{i+1}}_{t_i} \mu ds} + r_k$, where $r_k$ local error at step, $\mu$ - maximal eigen value of $\frac{J + J^T}{2}$ ($J$ is jacobian of system). But I didn't find they explanation...

Comment: Note: Queue Overflow did post the same [Question to Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/15900/how-to-estimate-the-local-error-and-the-global-error-for-runge-kutta-method), where it has received a prompt and thoughtful Answer with references to further reading.

Comment: How to close answer?

Comment: If you wish, there should be a "delete" option next to the "edit" link.  However it is not required to close the Question here.